# Bind a WPF combobox and get selecteditem to a richtextbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am using a dataset on the server, in this dataset I have a datatable that calls a stored procedure and returns column names from three tables. I call this stored procedure using a web service.

I manage to show all the column names in my combobox but when I want to click a button and insert selected column name into a richtextbox I get System.Data.DataRowView in the textbox instead.

My code:
'the combobox
            
                
                    
'if I don't have this textblock all the values are shown vertical instead of the normal horizontal lines

'the stored procedure
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE        (TABLE_NAME = 'Customer') OR
           (TABLE_NAME = 'Invoices') OR
           (TABLE_NAME = 'Orders')

'the button
    Private Sub btnAddColumnNames_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAddColumnNames.Click
        ' Add column names to the richtextbox
        Dim tr As New TextRange(rtbText.Selection.Start, rtbText.Selection.End)
        tr.Text = cboColumnNames.SelectedItem.ToString()
        rtbText.Focus()
    End Sub

Any suggestions on how to get the selected text in the combobox to the richtextbox?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `SelectedValuePath` of the ComboBox to the member that you want to bind to.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="..." SelectedValuePath="COLUMN_NAME" />
```

Then instead of using SelectedItem you would use SelectedValue.

```
Dim tr As New TextRange(rtbText.Selection.Start, rtbText.Selection.End)
tr.Text = CStr(cboColumnNames.SelectedValue)
rtbText.Focus()
```